# go revel undefined: sql or Txn

Tags: go, revel

mac highsierra
use mysql

https://paiza.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/03/23/paizacloud_golang_revel）

I'm trying to use the Revel framework for mysql.
 It's revel Tutorial booking.

what is error?

```
ERROR 18:33:28 watcher.go:270: Build detected an error                  error="Go Compilation Error (in app/controllers/gorm.go:31): undefined: sql"
```

before

```
ERROR 18:18:26 watcher.go:270: Build detected an error                  error="Go Compilation Error (in app/controllers/app.go:26): c.Txn undefined (type Application has no field or method Txn)"
```

I did this because I got an error before

controllers/gorm.go

```
type Transactional struct {
    *revel.Controller
    Txn *sql.Tx
}
```

After running it results in error
Please tell me how you can solve it

add 
controllers/app.go

```
package controllers

import (
    "github.com/revel/revel"
    "booking/app/models"
    "booking/app/routes"
    "database/sql"
)
type Application struct {
    *revel.Controller
}

func (c Application) Index() revel.Result {
    if c.connected() != nil {
        return c.Redirect(routes.Hotels.Index())
    }
    c.Flash.Error("Please log in first")
    return c.Render()
}

func (c Application) connected() *models.User {
    if c.ViewArgs["user"] != nil {
        return c.ViewArgs["user"].(*models.User)
    }
    if username, ok := c.Session["user"]; ok {
        return c.getUser(username.(string))
    }

    return nil
}
```

controllers/gorm.go

```
package controllers

import (
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    "github.com/revel/revel"
    "booking/app/models"
    "log"
    )


type GormController struct {
    *revel.Controller
    Txn *gorm.DB
}
func InitDB() {
    dbInfo, _ := revel.Config.String("db.info")
    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", dbInfo)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf("Failed gorm.Open: %v\n", err)
    }

    db.DB()
    db.AutoMigrate(&models.Booking{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&models.Hotel{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&models.User{})

    DB = db
}


func (c *GormController) SetDB() revel.Result {
    c.Txn = DB
    return nil
}

type Transactional struct {
    *revel.Controller
    Txn *sql.Tx
}
```

tree
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0APz.png)
maybe import miss?

Comment: Are the packages being imported correctly ?

Comment: add comments.
app.go and gorm.go
what is need import packages?

Comment: Show what code you have in file `app/controllers/gorm.go` on line `31` and file `app/controllers/app.go` on line `26`.

Comment: ... most probably in file `app/controllers/gorm.go` you're missing the import of the `"database/sql"` package. And in file `app/controllers/app.go` on line `26` you are referencing `c.Txn` where `c` is an instance of `Application` but you haven't defined the type `Application` as having a field `Txn`. So you should add that field to that type.

Comment: Application struct should have *GormController not *revel.Controller

Comment: >So you should add that field to that type.
What do I?

Comment: >Application struct should have *GormController not *revel.Controller


I edit controllers/app.go

`type Application struct {
 *Gorm.Controller
}`

But new error.
`ERROR 17:54:44 watcher.go:270: Build detected an error                  error="Go Compilation Error (in app/controllers/app.go:11): undefined: Gorm" 
`